# Navigating Images through a one knob slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, jquery-ui-slider

I want to flick through a set of 10 images with an one knob slider.
Imagine I have an image sequence and a knob position of 1.

Image 1 displayed
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
x - - - - - - - - -

If the user know drags the knob on the slider to the right with his mouse

Image 4 is displayed
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
- - - - x - - - - -

Basically I want to show always 1 image at a time but the user can flick the the images from left to right by dragging the knob on a slider like (http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/forms/slider/index.html)

Is there already a solution for this problem?

Thank you and enjoy your weekend.

Comment: Post what you have done so far.